# In developer mode, why do I still need to manually delete the directory "generated/code/{vendor}" when adding a dependency injection to a controller?

Tags: magento, magento2, code-generation

I'm building out a backend controller. Each time that I add a dependency injection into the constructor I have to execute `rm -r generated/code/{vendor}`. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The Magento 2 Documentation explains why:

> Suppose a Factory or Proxy class for a Customer class is generated and the Customer
>   class has new methods added to it. Because a Factory or Proxy exists on the file
>   system, it is not regenerated.
>
> However, the Factory or Proxy implementation is now
>   incomplete because it does not have the new methods. In this case, you must regenerate
>   the Factory or Proxy class.

In your case, the code was already generated prior to injecting a new class. Injecting a new class within the __construct() in your code will cause a mismatch of the __construct() in the generated code, which causes the error.

Deleting the generated code will cause Magento to re-construct the code, along with the newly added class within the __construct().

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html#codegen-over-why

Hope this helps!